# Have 2 container views. Need to change one to a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

So I have a main view controller...
and two view containers. Vcon1 and Vcon2
I have them talking to each other via delegates however I'm not sure how to change the view controller displayed...so a tap on a button in Vcon1 will change the Vcon2 to have a new view controller...

I have a navagation controller in Vcon2 however I'm not sure I want a "stack" of view controllers in there...just want to swap out one for another.

Any suggestions appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

If both of them have been added as subviews on the parentController's view, it's just a matter of calling `bringSubviewToFront`.

Else you can remove one of the view controllers, and proceed to add the other one. You can read more about view controller containment at [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/)

Comment: remove the one in Vcon2 and add a new one in Vcon2?